# Математическая задачка, алгоритм сортировки

Tags: c#, алгоритм, сортировка, математика

Ограничение по времени 5с, по памяти 256мб
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Моя реализация не проходит тест, по времени и памяти все ок, а вот с алгоритмом что-то не то наверное, может у кого-нибудь есть мысли? Или даже
советы по реализации

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Testing
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int numberOfTasks = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int numberOfTestDevice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] testTime = new int[numberOfTasks];

            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTasks; i++)
            {
                testTime[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            testTime = SortArray(testTime);
            int totalTime = 0;
            int x= 0;

            for (int i = 1; i <= testTime.Length; i++)
            {
                totalTime += ((x * 2) + 1) * testTime[i - 1];

                if (i % numberOfTestDevice == 0)
                    x++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(totalTime);
        }

        static int[] SortArray(int[] inputArray)
        {
            int[] countArray = new int[inputArray.Max() + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.Length; i++)
            {
                countArray[inputArray[i]]++;
            }
            int[] sortedArray = new int[inputArray.Length];
            int sortedArrayIndex = 0;
            for (int i = countArray.Length-1; i >=0; i--)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < countArray[i]; j++)
                {
                    sortedArray[sortedArrayIndex++] = i;
                }
            }
            return sortedArray;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Распишите заложенный в программу алгоритм - вычислять, что там придумано, тупо лень. PS. Вы учли, что тестирования НЕ могут проводиться параллельно на нескольких приборах?

Comment: Да, я это учел.

Comment: нет, не правильно

Comment: Неужели никто не знает

Answer (score 0):

Общее время выходило за предел int, поставил decimal